# How can I reverse data array of Firestore ? Angular 6

Tags: arrays, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, angular6, angularfire2

```
listItemAds() {
        this.itemList = this.afs.collection<Class>('Collection');

        this.itemList.snapshotChanges().subscribe(list => {
        this.itemArray = [];
        list.forEach(action => {
        const data = action.payload.doc.data() as Class;
        this.itemArray.push(data);
-->  this.itemArray.reverse(); // I try use this.itemArray.reverse(data.idNumber) ==> error
           });
         });
         console.log(this.itemArray);

      }
```

I wanna reverse data from New data to Old data , I set idNumber in object  ex:[1,2,3,4,5].

Note

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `orderBy` [query option](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md#4-querying-collections-in-angularfirestore) in your `collection` call.

The [Firebase documentation on ordering & limiting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) shows you how to use `orderBy` specifically.

Using the server to sort data results in better client performance.

```
this.itemList = this.afs.collection<Class>(
    'Collection',
    ref => ref.orderBy('idNumber', 'desc')
);
this.itemList.subscribe(list => {
    console.log(list);
});
```